# meaning: Wheat Belly

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've heard "beer belly," but what does "Wheat Belly" mean in the following book title?

> Wheat Belly: Lose the Wheat, Lose the Weight, and Find Your Path Back to Health

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a new expression, probably made up by this author. But the meaning is easy to guess from "beer belly".

A beer belly is fatness, caused by drinking beer (beer is high in calories). A wheat belly is fatness caused by eating wheat, or wheat-based food like bread.  Bread is also high in calories.

The author is suggesting that by reducing the amount of bread, cake and other food made with wheat, you will be able to lose weight.

Comment: It's all about the refined carbohydrates and the gluten in wheat that causes the "wheat belly" syndrome. It's not necessarily about being fat.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then why is "belly" used?

Comment: @Apollyon [*In its simplest form, Wheat Belly is really about two things: 1. eliminating wheat (and other gluten-containing grains such as barley and rye), and 2. managing carbohydrates/sugars to individual tolerance levels to manage blood sugar and promote weight-loss if desired.*](https://www.wheatbelly.com/articles/whatis) It's not really about being fat from eating foods high in carbohydrates, but promises of losing weight, especially from the belly area, is always going to catch the public eye.